# What is the best approach for Single Sign On Application Development that is lightweight?

Tags: web-applications, software

What is the best approach for Single Sign On Application Development that is lightweight?

By lightweight I mean not too much javascript. I know stackexchange does use single sign-on. Basically is the login credential stored as cookie? Or combination of IP-Address and other specific information about the logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use JavaScript in an SSO implementation. There are a number of [existing Single Sign On solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations) that do not utilize JavaScript. I suggest that you look at using one of these before you build SSO from scratch. I don't know if any of these qualify as "lightweight" in your book. Some will offer more features than others. Some are easier to set up than others. All should be fairly seamless to the end user.

If you do need to build SSO from scratch for whatever reason, you should look at the internals of an existing open source SSO solution like [CAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Technical+Overview) to get an idea of how you can implement.

Comment: Thanks. I should have checked wiki. I like JOSSO (since I am comfortable with Java Technology and also it supports non-java applications as well)